# Pop up for choosing client certificate shows at random times and lets me access protected directories without certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I have made 2 CSR(one for server and one for client shown below as *ssatClient* and *ssatServer*). After signing them with a valid CA certificate I verified them. Both of them display that the verification is okay.

I am using xampp to run an APACHE server with SSL connection.

**Configuration**

This is the content of **httpd-ssl.conf**

```
Listen 443
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:D:/xamppNew/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "D:/xamppNew/htdocs"
ServerName SSAT:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "D:/xamppNew/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "D:/xamppNew/apache/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/ssatServer.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/ssatServer.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "conf/SSAT_ca-chain.crt"
#SSLCACertificatePath conf/ssl.key/SSAT.crt"
#SLCACertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/SSAT.crt"
#SSLVerifyClient require 
#SSLCACertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/SSAT.crt 
#SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLCACertificateFile "conf/SSAT_ca-chain.crt"

<Location /protected> 
     SSLVerifyClient require 
     SSLVerifyDepth 3
</Location>
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "D:/xamppNew/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Virtual host setup shown below in the file **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName SSAT
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf\ssl.crt\ssatServer.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf\ssl.key\ssatServer.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "conf\SSAT_ca-chain.crt"
   <Location /protected> 
        SSLVerifyClient require 
        SSLVerifyDepth 3
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Problem**

I am trying to authenticate the client via the ssat:443 site.Setting the  tag with the *SSLVerifyClient require* option in virtual host lets the users access this directory only if they have a valid certificate signed by my CA. No matter if I delete the trusted certificates or personal certificates in Google Chrome I can still access the /protected directory which i am not suppose to without a valid client certificate. Sometimes if I try  reconnecting after 30 or 40 minutes I get the pop up which lets me choose a client certificate. After choosing it, the server  lets me get into the /protected tab and from then on till the next pop up it lets me access it no matter how many times I restart the server or delete/re-add valid and non valid certificates.

**Questions**

Am I doing something wrong in the configuration? The "Connection is secure" always works for the server certificate.
Is there any way I can delete the "cached" certificates so every time I want to access the /protected tab it will ask me for a certificate via the pop-up?

Sorry for the long post

Comment: Did you try with another client, either a browser or `wget`/`curl`/`openssl s_client`?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek i tried to connect via openssl s_client ssat:443 but in the list i see No client certificates CA names were sent. Also i tried connecting via incognito window on Google Chrome with a hope that it will show the pop up but that doesnt work either.